# VSU 2012 - entry point must be defined

Tags: .net, winforms, c++-cli

Visual Studio Ultimate 2012 - entry point must be defined.

Hello. I had files:

> MyForm.h
>
> Forma.h
>
> MyForm.cpp

In the Myform.cpp i had

```
#include "MyForm.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
void main(array<String^>^args){
Application::EnableVisualStyles();
Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
Project1::MyForm form;
Application::Run(%form);    
}
```

But when i try to relase it , i have error:

> Error 2   error LNK1561: entry point must be defined

Comment: Do you have a main function anywhere?

Comment: This is C++/CLI (.NET runtime), not native C++ code. Are you compiling this with the Common Runtime Support switch enabled?

Comment: Hmmm... `void main(array<String^>^args)`.

Comment: This is not C++. Retag your question with the proper language tag.

Comment: I strongly recommend using one of the *project templates* to get started. That will ensure that all of the settings are correct and that everything compiles properly.

Comment: What is the value of the property `Entry point` in `Property > Linker > Entry Point` ? Try to enter the mangled name of main.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to your problem, I believe, is in two steps:

1. press right click on your project file,choose "Properties", "Linker", "System", "SubSystem" = Windows
   [image]
2. And also, "Linker", "Advanced", "Entry Point" and type "Main"... M: is in upper case.

   [image]

Press ctrl + F5 to test. You can design the form as normal once everything checks out.

**NOTE:**It is an unsubtle hint that they want you to stop creating C++/CLI Winforms applications. The plumbing is still in place however, at least for VS2012 and VS2013. This might not be the case in a future one.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include "MyForm.h"
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace testing; 
//go to MyForm.h and look for [namespace ****] where **** is the name of your project..mines name is testing. :)


STAThreadAttribute;
void main(){
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application::Run(gcnew MyForm());
}
```